# Can a neural network be used for this?

Tags: neural-network, pattern-recognition

I wan't to create a program that can tell what you "Want" from an input. IE: when you tell siri to find a place to eat, it knows what you mean. I was thinking of using a neural network to try and recognize what the person means based on training which is done when tasks are complete. Is this a viable solution for a pattern recognition or should I go with something else?

Answer (score 0):

*Though your question is a bit vague:*

#### *Try something else*

I think I would recommend you to look into `Decision Trees` instead. If you don't rely on having to voice recognition, then decision trees will be much faster to construct than a neural network with the appropriate training examples.

[See this for an introduction to `decision trees`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_tree)